# Struts2 jsp textfields are appearing outside of fieldset

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, legend, fieldset

When I put textfields inside the fieldset in struts2, it appears outside the fieldset in the brower.
Here is the code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ABD7E4">
<p align="center">Sign Up Page</p>

<s:form method="post" action="org.pritesh.action.hello">
<fieldset>
<legend>Tenant Details</legend>
<s:textfield name="tenantName" label="Tenant Name" required="true" />
<s:textfield name="websiteName" label="Website Name" required="true" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend>Hello</legend>
<s:textfield name="tenantPhone" label="Phone number" required="true" />
</fieldset>
<s:submit></s:submit>
</s:form>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: @RomanC Probably "why are the fields outside the fieldset". While I'm all for people asking questions accurately, when it's this obvious, I don't see a compelling reason to not just answer the question.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm not sure you guess correctly the question OP might ask. It could be "How to fix the layout using default theme and template".

Answer (score 1):

You are using the default "xhtml" theme which renders table rows/cells for form fields and labels.

If you want to use your own HTML/DOM layout you should consider either using the "simple" theme (this has some drawbacks, like no automatic error message display), rolling your own theme, etc.

You can also use the "simple" theme on individual components, which might be adequate.

For future reference, understanding *why* things are appearing as they are is as simple as examining the generated HTML output. This would show you the extra elements that are messing with your layout. That would lead you to try to understand what the custom tags are doing, which would lead you to the theme and template functionality that is core to Struts 2. The docs are your friend!